# htaccess rewrite rule accesing folder without moving it

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an root folder like this:

```
ROOT
|- Service
|  |- Admin
|
|- Service 2
```

I'm interesting in accessing the `admin` folder from service folder

To access the admin path via url i use `mydomain.com/Service/Admin`

Is there any way to make it access like this `mydomain.com/Admin` without moving folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(Admin/.*)$ Service/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^Admin/ Service/Admin/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I haven't tested this, but i believe it should work